# how to change type of chart while DataBind?

Tags: c#, charts

I have found new (for me), excellent and comfortable way to bind data to chart  - **DataBindCrossTable**.  It is very fast and comfortable when I import data form my db. A few lines :

```
    (...)
OracleDataReader myreader = ocom.ExecuteReader(CommandBehavior.CloseConnection);
DataTable dt = new DataTable();
dt.Load(myreader);
this.chart1.DataBindCrossTable((dt as IListSource).GetList(), "PROGRAM_NAME", "DATE", "MINUTE", "Label=Minute");
```

and graph is ready !

Now the question: By default column graph is generated. Because there is no need to create series I am not able to change type of graph. How to set my graph to StackedColumn  ( or any other) ?

There is a progress!  I am able to change type of chart by adding

```
foreach (Series cs in chart1.Series) 
{
   cs.ChartType = SeriesChartType.StackedColumn;
}
```

But now holes between happens like below:

[image]

so how to avoid holes ?